# Dont scroll collectionview when keyboard is displayed

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield

Please help me, I have a UICollectionView with cells that are the size of the entire screen.  On one of the cells I have a UITextField where they enter text into.  However when they click on the UITextField, the keyboard gets presented but when it presents, it slides the collectionview up so basically the bottom of the collectionviews frame is at the top of the keyboard.  How can I get this to stop where would I look in the code to figure this out?

This is shared code and Im having diffucultly figuring out where to look!

Answer (score 1):

You can  check for registered keyboard notification, may be you can fine the code in that for the change you require, or share the code.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
}
```